# Cannot connect django to postgres running inside docker container

Tags: django, postgresql, docker-compose

My django app is not dockerized, but I run postgres inside docker container using `docker-compose.yml` script. After `docker-compose up` I can connect to db with dbeaver, but not with django app. Every time I'm getting an error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: 
Temporary failure in name resolution
```

File `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"
      - POSTGRES_USER="postgres"
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD="postgres"
      - POSTGRES_DB="postgres"
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
volumes:
  postgres_data
```

Django project file `config/settings.py`:

```
...
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': env.str("DB_NAME"),
        'USER': env.str("DB_USER"),
        'PASSWORD': env.str("DB_PASS"),
        'HOST': env.str("DB_HOST"),
        'PORT': env.decimal("DB_PORT")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It was some kind of pipenv error. When I restarted terminal and executed `pipenv shell` again and then `python manage.py runserver` everything worked just fine